# Laravel schedules on distributed app

Tags: php, laravel, redis, distributed

My app runs on 3 servers behind a load balancer. Therefore it's stateless, all data is stored in redis and MySQL.

If my machines are running the artisan cron scheduler I'm assuming the same task will be run 3 times. Once on each machine, as there is no knowledge of what's been run shared between them aka a database table.

What are the solutions?

Comment: Is the redis database shared across the servers?

Comment: Yes it is shared, clustered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **edit:** In recent versions of Laravel, [this is now built-in](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#running-tasks-on-one-server).
>
> ```
> $schedule->command('foo:bar')->onOneServer();
> ```

We do this in Artisan commands that should only run on one server per cron execution:

```
public function handle()
    if(!Cache::add(get_class($this), true, 0.5)) {
        return false;
    }
```

`Cache::add` is synchronous and will return false if the key already exists, so even if all three servers execute at the exact same microsecond only one server will continue to the rest of the task.

Another common option is enabling the cron on just a single server in the cluster, or having a dedicated server for cron itself.

Comment: What about a server that Pings on a schedule? Could that also work?

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan I'm not clear what you mean by "pings".

Comment: Pings a route, accessed a route. On that route I boot the artisan scheduler

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan That'd work, yes, but I'm not sure I'd run cron via a route like that. HTTP timeouts wouldn't be fun to account for if your crons take a while to run.

Comment: I'm selecting this as the answer. Distributed selection of execution seems better then a leader pattern.

Comment: !! "To utilize this feature, your application must be using the memcached or redis cache driver as your application's default cache driver. In addition, all servers must be communicating with the same central cache server." !!

Answer (score 2):

If your redis server is shared across the servers, you can create some logic like electing a leader appserver.

Your app logic should check the leader before processing. Sample snippet:

```
if(redis.get("LEADER").equals(currentappserver))
process();
else if(redis.get("LEADER")==null && selectLeader()) -> a lua script call.
process();
```

Since redis is single threaded write a logic like this snippet in a lua script:

```
selectLeader()
if redis.get("LEADER")==null
redis.set("LEADER",current_node)
return true;
else
return false;
```

It will be atomic and only one leader thread will be available always.

P.s: Codes I have provided are vauge pseudo code not the exact code.

Comment: That's fairly neat.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 5.4 supports multi-server setups using scheduler** if upgrading is an option.

It uses a similar method as the accepted answer from ceejayoz.

> Instead of using the file system to store a lock file, we use the cache store to allow any server to lock/check scheduled events.

https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/69